# SSRS Loop through data, adding a new title if the chapter/section changes

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm building an SSRS report in Report Builder 3.0 (2014). I have five sections of data I'm working with: inspection number, chapter, section, code, and description. The report is only going to show data for one inspection, so all data is filtered on InspNo first. There are often multiple codes associated with an InspNo.

What I have: for every code associated with an inspection, the code is listed along with its description.

What I need: I need to add the chapter and section info, but only when it changes. For example, let's say the codes associated with an inspection are 302.7, 304.10, 304.12, and 505.1. I would like the result to be as follows:

Chapter 3
Section 302
302.7 - Description

Section 304
304.10 - Description
304.12 - Description

Chapter 5
Section 505
505.1 - Description

I have tried using Lists, but the chapter and section get repeated for every code. Any ideas how to make it work?

****UPDATE****
I'm getting closer to a solution. Right now I'm using a combination of textboxes and lists. The chapters and sections are text boxes, and the codes/descriptions are lists. All of the elements have a visibility expression using InStr. The lists are working perfectly. However the text boxes are giving me issues.

It seems my visibility expressions on elements outside of lists are only looking at the first piece of the pulled data. In the example above, Section 302's visibility expression is =IIF(InStr(Fields!FAILEDCODE.Value, "302") > 0, False, True). This is working great because the first code is 302.7. Section 304's visibility expression is =IIF(InStr(Fields!FAILEDCODE.Value, "304") > 0, False, True). This text box is always hidden. It seems like Report Builder is only checking this InStr value against the first line of data, not the entire set. Does anyone know if this is accurate or if there's a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried using a table grouped by chapter and section?

Comment: I wanted to use a table at first, but the chapter and section info is not part of my dataset. As of now, they are being manually typed in a text box.